# How do I effectively model actions to a reply from a query, which will require different actions?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

Ok  so I have a query. It returns a model with a bunch of bool flags. Based on these flags I can run  a bunch of if checks returning early when we are done with an action or falling through if no checks match.

```
var queryResult = complexQuery
if (queryResult.IsBroke)
{
    letPeopleKnow();
    return;
 }

if(queryResult.RetryNeeded)
{
   doARetry();
   return;
}
```

...... and more scenarios some of which are then nested

I enapsulate setting the state  based on myriad rules  on the model returned to hide this from calling class.

Ive TDDd and therefore I have no more or no less than I need  with various refactorings for readability etc (not shown here) but I am loate the refactor to a pattern (perhaps chain of responsobility or strategy) just for the sake of it.

I did have an idea of modelling a specific return type for each scenario and/ encapsulating action in this or providing  ability to attach an action.  I am a liitle rusty I guess at breaking stuff out coherently.

Comment: Can someone add in code highlighting cant see whats needed on mobile web version..

Comment: What are the `letPeopleKnow()` and `doRety` and so on methods? What do they do in general?

Comment: @gilad, thanks....

Comment: @gilad, one throws an exception the other publishes a domain event so there are other dependencies...

Comment: And different domain events for different scenarios.